# Pick-up value in data frame correspondent to value without looping

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have

```
FORCADA_ALEATORIOS <- c(0.77503776, 0.95981560, 0.43858290, 0.96340018,
                        0.40830180, 0.27587142, 0.09719325, 0.87138411, 0.18396708, 
                        0.36734687, 0.50293107, 0.05382047)
```

And a Data Frame (`BASE_DADOS`) like that below

```
MEDIANA     PERCENTUAL_ACUMULADO_ANTERIOR     PERCENTUAIS_ACUMULADOS
   17                  0.0000000                    0.9354839
  1308                 0.9354839                    0.9677419
  1656                 0.9677419                    1.0000000
```

I need to pick up the `MEDIANA` column value that the `FORCADA_ALEATORIOS` is between `PERCENTUAL_ACUMULADO_ANTERIOR` and `PERCENTUAIS_ACUMULADOS` without looping and in the best efficient way because I'll several times like one million.

Expected Result in this case:

```
(17,1308,17,1308,17,17,1656,17,17,17,17,17)
```

Below is the code that I built, but slow.

```
for (z in 1:12)
      {
  w=1
  while ((FORCADA_ALEATORIOS[z]>=BASE_DADOS[w,2] & FORCADA_ALEATORIOS[z]<BASE_DADOS[w,3] & 
            w<=length(BASE_DADOS)) | (FORCADA_ALEATORIOS[z]>=BASE_DADOS[w,3] & 
                                      w<=length(BASE_DADOS)) )
    {
        ALEATORIOS_FREQUENCIA[z]<-BASE_DADOS[w,1]
        w=w+1
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(FORCADA_ALEATORIOS, 
function(x) {
mdf[(mdf['PERCENTUAL_ACUMULADO_ANTERIOR'] <= x) & 
    (mdf['PERCENTUAIS_ACUMULADOS'] >= x)]}))[,1]

##  [1]   17 1308   17 1308   17   17   17   17   17   17   17   17
```

***Data:***

```
 mdf <- structure(list(MEDIANA = c(17L, 1308L, 1656L), PERCENTUAL_ACUMULADO_ANTERIOR = c(0, 
     0.9354839, 0.9677419), PERCENTUAIS_ACUMULADOS = c(0.9354839,                           
     0.9677419, 1)), .Names = c("MEDIANA", "PERCENTUAL_ACUMULADO_ANTERIOR",                 
     "PERCENTUAIS_ACUMULADOS"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```